# Can I get Photographic Paper with lower ISO?

Tags: iso, diy, paper, pinhole-cameras

I have been playing around with pinhole cameras using photographic paper (instead of film). Great fun. But when I buy photographic paper, I don't seem to have any options for different ISOs, like I do with film. (I have 5" x 7" Ilford Multigrade IV RV paper.)

What I would really like is photographic paper that is less light sensitive, so I can do a longer exposures. Say, paper with an ISO of 5 instead of 100.

Is there any way to tell the ISO of photographic paper? Does anyone manufacture photographic paper with lower ISO ratings?

Comment: I know it's not directly what you're asking, but have you considered just sticking a ND filter in front of your pinhole?

Comment: Excellent question! My experience is that different papers have different resistive levels. I've used Kodak and Ilford and noticed that Kodak was more sensitive. You may also want to see [this](http://photo.net/black-and-white-photo-printing-finishing-forum/003WpC) where an ilford customer service rep talks about it.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Ah! That's a really fun idea. And I can try that for shorter exposures. But the average exposure I am aiming for is 2-6 months. So I don't want to leave an expensive ND filter unattended that long. Great idea for a 3-30 minute exposure though!

Comment: @theJollySin Can you post some of your images? I want to know what a 4 month exposure looks like!

Comment: @SailorCire LOL. Give me a few months? My last batch of cameras were all destroyed by people who probably thought they were trash. I will hide them better this time. Check out this article though: http://itchyi.squarespace.com/thelatest/2010/7/20/the-longest-photographic-exposures-in-history.html

Comment: If you're looking at multi-month exposures, you should certainly read [this question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40526/how-to-take-extremely-long-multiple-month-exposure-photos).

Comment: Perhaphs find a way to make a smaller pinhole? An insuline needle or simething like that?

Comment: @Rafael Sadly, pinholes are diffraction limited. Anything below 0.18mm will be too blurry to be useful. I aim for 0.2-0.25mm, and that's about the smallest anyone sells too.

Comment: Oh. Interesting info.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Maybe you are right. If I shoot with Black and White paper I can stick a cheap ND filter in front: like a welding mask replacement lens. The color cast won't matter with B&W paper.

Comment: FYI: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62364/38156

Comment: @theJollySin I honestly don't think that "use an ND filter" is an answer to "Can I get photographic paper with lower ISO?" (which is why I posted it as a comment in the first place :-)). Normally we frown on major edits to questions, particularly those with answers, but you could *consider* making this question more "how do I do very long exposure pinhole camera photography?" - but in order not to invalidate DrMoishe Pippik's answer, you'll probably need to keep a mention of photographic paper in there. Alternatively, ask an entirely new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a *really* insensitive paper, try [blueprint paper photography](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/blueprint/blueprint.html) or [diazo paper photography](http://www.markfickett.com/stuff/artPage.php?id=381). These sheets are comparatively inexpensive and are available in *large* sizes. You can even [make blueprint paper yourself](http://chemistry.about.com/od/colorchemistryprojects/a/How-To-Make-Blueprint-Paper.htm).

See this on the [blueprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blueprint) process.

And *do* post your images!